# How to map data from one dataframe into a column in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two separate dataframes representing different types of time-based data. One contains hundreds of thousands of timestamps spread across several months. This dataframe has columns representing the month of the year, the time of the day, and the measured temperature. The second dataframe consists of replacement temperatures for each month/hour combination. The data looks roughly as follows:

df1

| Timestamp | Month | Hour | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 10 |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:05 | 1 | 0 | 11 |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:07 | 1 | 0 | 8 |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:15 | 1 | 0 | 12 |
| 1/1/2021 00:01:00 | 1 | 1 | 13 |

etc.

df2

| Hour | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | 12 | 10 | 12 | etc |
| 1 | 10 | 11 | 14 | 15 | etc |
| 2 | 8 | 7 | 12 | 16 | etc |

df2 contains a row for each hour of the day, and a column for each month of the year (In the real data set the months are numeric, I wrote the names to make the description clear).

I need to map the data contained for the month/hour in df2 to the Temperature column in df 1. So df1, after editing, should appear as follows.

New df1

| Timestamp | Month | Hour | Temperature |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:00 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:05 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:07 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 1/1/2021 00:00:15 | 1 | 0 | 9 |
| 1/1/2021 00:01:00 | 1 | 1 | 10 |

I have made it work using a nested for loop, as follows:

```
for month in df2.columns:
    for hour in df2.index:
        dT = df2.loc[hour, month]
        df1.loc[(df1['Month'] == month) & (df1['Hour'] == hour), 'Temperature'] = dT
```

The nested for loop cycles through all months and hours in df2, locates the cells in df1 with the matching month and hour, then sets the temperature equal to the temperature read out of df2.

But this code is both hard to read and super slow to execute. Does somebody know a better way??

Thanks!

Comment: Can you test [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68706577/16343464) and give me feedback on the running time? It is possible to make it faster by skipping the step to extract the month name and reworking the second dataframe instead. Let me know…

Answer (score 1):

Let's call df1 and df2 your two dataframes in order.

First, make sure Timestamp is datetime and extract the month short name (we could also map the Month number to short name)

```
df1['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Timestamp'])
df1['Month_name'] = df1['Timestamp'].dt.month_name().str[:3]
```

*NB. if speed is critical, then skip the above step and rework your df2 to have months numbers in place of months names as columns, then in the final step use the "Month" column of df1 to perform the merge*

Then rework df2 to unstack the months (this can be applied directly in the next step or saved in a variable):

```
df2.set_index('Hour').unstack().rename('Temperature')
```

Finally, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) the two:

```
df1.merge(df2.set_index('Hour').unstack().rename('Temperature'),
          left_on=['Month_name', 'Hour'],
          right_index=True,
          suffixes=('_old', ''),
         )
```

output:

```
            Timestamp  Month  Hour  Temperature_old Month_name  Temperature
0 2021-01-01 00:00:00      1     0               10        Jan            9
1 2021-01-01 00:00:05      1     0               11        Jan            9
2 2021-01-01 00:00:07      1     0                8        Jan            9
3 2021-01-01 00:00:15      1     0               12        Jan            9
4 2021-01-01 00:01:00      1     1               13        Jan           10
```

If you want to keep only the new temperatures, add `.drop(['Month', 'Temperature_old'], axis=1)`

Comment: Hi mozway. Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, it isn't working. When I run the .merge step I get an error saying that it's trying to merge int and object columns, and that I should use pd.concat instead. Here's the specific error:

ValueError: You are trying to merge on int32 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat.

I'm very confused by this error because, when I check the column types, they do line up. Month is int (e.g. 'Jan' is now '1'). Hour is int. The index of df2.unstack().rename('Temperature') is a tuple, but the left_on is too. Any thoughts?

Comment: How come the index is a tuple? Is your dataset different than the example? Can you provide it?

Comment: The problem arises when unstacking df2. Originally 'hour' is the index (My apologies for not specifying that originally). When I unstack it becomes a multi-level index of (month, hour). But the code you provided looks like it's expecting a tuple so I wouldn't expect that to be a problem.

I can upload df2, but not df1. Is there a good way to do that? I've never asked a question on SO before and don't see a clear way to do that.